# Socket.IO doesn't connect to my mobile phone

Tags: socket.io, p5.js

I'm trying to make a simple Node app using p5.js.
The sketch runs perfectly fine, if I open multiple Firefox windows everything does what it should do.
The thing is: when I type "192.168.0.101" in on my mobile phone, it doesn't register as a new connection in my terminal, yet the sketch does load on my phone.

Here's a link to [my code](https://github.com/WalrusGumboot/node-drawing-app).

I am connected to the same Wi-Fi network as the notebook I'm running my Node app on.

Why does this happen? Can I fix this? If so, how?
Thanks in advance,
WalrusGumboot

---

**System specifications:**

- **OS:** Windows 8.1
- **Computer model:** Acer Aspire Switch 10
- **Phone model:** Huawei P Smart

Comment: Does it work if you try it from multiple computers?

Comment: I haven't tried doing that. I'll test tomorrow.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I've just tried on an iMac. The error message said that the Mac `"couldn't connect to the server."`
Typing in "socket.id" in the JavaScript console returned "undefined". The thing is, the sketch did load properly.

Comment: Did you open the Windows Firewall on your server so that it will accept incoming connections on the port 3000 you are using?  If not, you can only connect to your server from that computer, not from any other computer.

Comment: Oh my god sorry for not responding sooner but that was literally the problem! Thank you so much!